# Amid (The Spreading Of) Rumor Of

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage

I have a question about a possible error in some [dictionary](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/amid) entry for the preposition "amid":

> while noisy, busy, or confused events are happening - used in writing or news reports

So, "*amid*" should be followed by some "*event*".  Yet the sample usage in the same dictionary reads:

> The dollar has fallen in value ***amid rumors*** of weakness in the US economy.

A "*rumor*" is not an event.  So, is "***amid rumors*** of ..." wrong?  Would this rewrite:

> The dollar has fallen in value ***amid the spreading*** of rumors of weakness in the US economy.

,be better?

Comment: *Amid rumors* is fine.  You are taking the definition far too literally. Definitions are approximations of meaning.  It might have said "while noise, bustle, or confusion is going on all around".  Rumor is often compared to wild fire that spreads rapidly and burns uncontrollably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The press (which has it's own language and rules of grammar it seems) use the literary meaning of **amid** - *to be among or surrounded by*. Therefore, *"amid rumours"* is perfectly acceptable, and in fact the expected language used by journalists.

*I should point out as a British English speaker, typing the word rumour with only one **u** feels icky.*